# Should a p element be put inside a footer element?

Tags: html

I'm making a simple footer, and I'm used to make them like this:

```html
<footer>
  <p>Hello Word</p>
</footer>
```

But this would work too

```html
<footer>Eliaz Bobadilla</footer>
```

So knowing this is not necessary, is it recommended?

Comment: A paragraph should represent a block or text, so if your footer should include text it's totally fine to use <p>-elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The footer HTML element represents a footer for its nearest sectioning content or sectioning root element. A  typically contains information about the author of the section, copyright data or links to related documents.

To answer your question, it is OK, but you usually use footer for some info, like links and address, and in that case you would add them to a or address tag.

Answer (score 0):

Paragraph tags that are located within a div, within the footer element for developer.mozilla site so I would say it is okay.

Comment: I mean....tags don't 'always' have to be in a `div`

Comment: It was a typo...

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, `footer` is a semantical container, it can have a `p` or just plain text, it doesn't matter, both are correct.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary, but if you want write more elements -it would be reccomended